# StringFormat "N2" issue (?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a question somewhat curious. I'm using "StringFormat = N2". When I have the value "1,00", I place the cursor behind "," I press "backspace" and the number becomes, magically in "100,00". WTF! I need to remain "1,00"
It happens almost always "100,00" = "10.000,00" etc etc

```
<TextBox Height="40" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Width="320">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="Weight"
                 StringFormat="N2"
                 ConverterCulture="es-AR"
                 UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: Hmm, when I remove a comma from `1,00` it looks like 100

Comment: @ThomasWeller Thx, please press 4 times "123" (1.231.231.231,00) and try to delete with backspace (from the end)

Comment: Ok, maybe describe it in the question like that. Sounds more like a use case then deleting the comma

Answer (score 4):

Two observations:

1. StringFormat=N2 tells the UI that the value in the textbox should be formatted as a number with two decimal places.
2. In the ConverterCultuer= es-AR tell the UI that the decimal place character is a comma.

So let's take this step by step:

1. Value is 1 (displayed as 1,00)
2. Remove the comma, but leave the zeros
3. Value is now 100 (displayed as 100,00)

I don't see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is this property:

```
UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"
```

This forces WPF to send a value back to the view-model every time the contents of the `TextBox` changes, e.g. because a character has been typed in it or deleted from it.

Suppose your `TextBox` has the text `1,00`, with the view-model containing the `double` value `1.0`.  You then delete the comma, so your text-box has the text `100`.  Because the text has changed, this forces WPF to update the view-model from the view.  The string `100` becomes the `double` value `100.0`, which is set in your view-model's `Weight` property.

If your view-model class implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` (I am assuming it does), it will then fire a `PropertyChanged` event for the `Weight` property.  WPF listens to this event and then updates the contents of the `TextBox` from the `Weight` property.  As a consequence your `TextBox` then contains the text `100,00`, as this is the result of formatting the value `100.0` using the `N2` format string.

The easiest fix is to remove the property `UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"`.  This causes WPF to only update the view-model when the `TextBox` loses focus.  You are dealing with numeric input, and it's quite possible that intermediate values are not valid or could be misinterpreted, so it's best to wait until the user has finished entering a numeric value before attempting to do anything with it.